# WCF service as a client and as a service?

Tags: wcf

I have to create a WCF 4.0 (VS 2010) service (`MyWCFService`) which is both service (consumed from MS Dynamics AX) and client (will consume some external XML web service).

So basically the flow is:

1. MS Dynamics AX will call MyWCFService
2. MyWCFService call external XML web service
3. External XML web service return result to MyWCFService
4. MyWCFService return result to MS Dynamics AX

Are there some special consideration concerning this scenario which I should be aware of?

What about asynchronously consuming, should the client of my `MyWCFService` and the service itself make asynchronously calls?

Can you point me to some documentation which review/discuss this “middle man” service pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing that you need to watch out for here is the security and logging.

- What is the security context in which you will be accessing the MS Dynamics AX service with
- How do you control who can do what on the service
- How do you keep track of what users have done

The worst case scenario is an open external web service, which accesses the MS Dynamics using an admin user. So that external unathorised users have full control of your backend system.

Comment: It is the MS Dynamics AX which will call MyWCFService which will call the 3d party external service. So i do not see the security problem here. The call goes from internall to external.